# Работа с динамической памятью

Tags: c++, память

Хотел сделать сортировку матрицы, работая с ней как с одномерным массивом, то есть перемещаться напрямую по памяти.
Если делать статичный массив `int a[2][2]`, то по запросу `std::cout << *(*a+3);` я получаю тот самый `a[1][1]`, который мне и нужен. Но как только я сделал динамический массив

```
int** b = new int*[2];  
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)  
{
    b[i] = new int[2];
}
```

то при том же обращении `std::cout << *(*b+3);` и при любом значении, вне 1-й строки (для данной матрицы при 1 и 2 выводит значение, а при 3 и 4 выводит 0) выводится 0. 
Покопался в этом (если я не ошибаюсь, то `std::cout << *(b + i);` должен выводить адрес 0-го элемента i-й строки)
получилось что если создавать массив на n-nое количество строк и
от 1 до 6 элеметов - на каждую строку выделяется 32 байта
от 7 до 10 элементов - на каждую строку по 48 байта
от 11 до 14 - по 64 байта
от 15 до 18 - по 80 байт
и так далее
Поясните пожалуйста как это работает

Comment: То что вы называет динамическим массивом таковым не является, вы просто выделяете память для массива либо на стеке, либо в куче. Динамическими принято называть массивы которые могут менять свой размер в процессе работы программы, для Си++ это будет std::vector. К стати это распространенная ошибка новичков, и кто только их этому учит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень ясно зачем забивать себе голову адресной арифметикой, если уж речь идёт о C++. Но если уж так хочется...

Либо вам нужно выделить непрерывный кусок памяти размером NxM, и обращаться к злементу `[n][m]` как к `*(data + m*N + n)`.

Либо так:

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 2;
const size_t M = 3;

int main()
{
    // здесь мы выделили один непрерывный блок указателей:
    int **data = new int *[N];

    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        // а здесь мы выделяем другие непрерывные блоки,
        // уже для переменных. адреса которых записываем в 
        // элементы массива, полученного на предыдущем
        // этапе. ну и заполним их чем-нибудь для контроля:
        data[i] = new int[M];
        for( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
            *( data[i] + j ) = i * M + j;
            // оно же:
            // data[i][j] = i * M + j;
        }
    }

    // проверим что получилось:
    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        for( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
            std::cout << *( data[i] + j ) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Объявления `int a[2][2]` и `int **a` не эквивалентны и имеют принципиально разный смысл.

Первое - массив 2х2, создаваемый на стеке, память под который представляет собой непрерывный участок памяти

Второе - указатель на указатель. Другими словами, когда вы делаете `int **a = new *int[2]`, выделяется область памяти для двух указателей. Т.к. оператор `new` выделяет память в куче, то она выделяется более-менее произвольно. Получается, у вас есть блок памяти с массивом указателей на какие-то другие области памяти.

Comment: Это понятно, но почему память на строку выделяется не `i*sizeof(T)`, где i - это количество элементов в строке, а блоками?

Comment: Какую строку? Я не очень понимаю, что вас смущает.

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg, в `int** b = new int*[2];` вы сделали (где-то в памяти) массив из 2-х указателей, а в `b[i] = new int[2];` делаете очередной массив из 2-х int и запоминаете его адрес в 1-м массиве указателей. Для "матрицы" 2х2 всего вы выделяете память 3 раза (м.б. вразброс). Для доступа к i,j-му элементу просто пишите `b[i][j]`, например, для вывода последнего `cout << b[1][1] << ...`

Comment: Наверно речь про размер первого массива. Тут дело в том, что нет разницы на что указатель - его размер зависит от платформы 32/64 бита.

Answer (score 1):

Создать многомерный массив в куче можно так:
`int(*b)[2] = new int[2][2];`

Или если доступен C++11, то можно упростить до:
`auto b = new int[2][2];`

Обращаться к элементам:

```
b[1][1] = 42;
int x = b[1][1];
int y = *(*b + 3);
```

Удалить:
`delete[] b;`

Comment: ошибка: conflicting declaration `'int (* b)[2]'`     
     `int (*b)[2] = new int[2][2];`

Comment: уверены что объявление b уникльно?

Comment: пример: https://ideone.com/tNSpcn